# Is this statement accurate. And if not what are the chances

Tags: statistics

Assaults by firearm kill about 13,000 people in the US each year, which translates to a roughly 1-in-315 lifetime chance of death from gun violence.

Answer (score 1):

Seems accurate. Life expectancy in the US is about 80 years. So $330,000,000 / 13,000 / 80 \approx 317$.

Comment: Someone may question 330 million and 80 yrs, but a nice answer.